# Word definitions in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dictionary Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771559/dictionary-application)

I need a large amount of word definitions for my iOS program. Is there a way to get definitions (as strings) either at realtime or at least pre-upload them before compile time. UIReferenceLibraryViewController does not allow to extract a definition...

Comment: Ideally I don't want to retrieve them via internet at real-time

Comment: @user1486477 The last answer to that Josh linked you to includes a developer promoting his off off-line solution...

Comment: http://www.lexicontext.com/ is a very good product, used it myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) may be of interest to you

There is also an inexpensive iOS ready adaptation of it: [lexicontext](http://www.lexicontext.com/about.html) (I have no affiliation or experience using this).